# Tensorflow model works in Python but not in C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

For a little background, my main goal is to use Tensorflow's C++ API to classify an image and time it on different systems.

I have used [Ry's model converter](https://github.com/ry/tensorflow-vgg16) to convert his Caffe model to Tensorflow, and it produces the vgg16.tfmodel file, which appears to be a .pb file, once you open it up.

Using Ry's tf_forward.py to run this resulting file seems to work perfectly, classifying cats, dogs, etc. However, when I modify the label_image example (tensorflow/examples/label_image/) to use my new vgg16.pb file, something appears to go wrong.

Here's the output of classifying the picture of the cat from the tensorflow-vgg16 example:

```
I tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:195] n03729826 matchstick (644): 0.0762781
I tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:195] n01930112 nematode, nematode worm, roundworm (111): 0.0493599
I tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:195] n03196217 digital clock (530): 0.0317698
I tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:195] n03666591 lighter, light, igniter, ignitor (626): 0.0313151
I tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:195] n04286575 spotlight, spot (818): 0.0252088
```

and here are the settings that I use in my modification of label_image/main.cc:

```
string image = "tensorflow/examples/label_image/data/cat.jpg"; //from Ry's project
string graph = "tensorflow/examples/label_image/data/vgg16.pb"; //renamed from Ry's project
string labels ="tensorflow/examples/label_image/data/synset.txt"; //from Ry's project
int32 input_width = 224;
int32 input_height = 224;
int32 input_mean = 128;
int32 input_std = 128;
string input_layer = "mul";
string output_layer = "prob";
bool self_test = false;
string root_dir = "";
```

I've also tried freeze_graph.py to get the model and weights, but I could never get it to work properly. After tracing everything back a bit,I ran into protobuf code and got a bit stuck. Any help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking at this in the future, this problem was caused by using the wrong input layer name.