# Model trained with TF-slim works perfectly with python inference but gives totally wrong results with C++ one

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I have trained a two-class `MobileNet_v1` using [TF-slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#training-a-model-from-scratch) on my own custom data. Testing the model with eval_image_classifier.py code, [this command](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#evaluating-performance-of-a-model), results in 0.936 accuracy. As my actual goal is to deploy the model with c++ code, I froze the model using [freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) with the following command:

```
python3 freeze_graph.py --input_graph=/path/to/graph.pbtxt \
      --input_checkpoint=/path/to/model.ckpt-CHECKPOINTNUMBER \
      --output_graph=frozen_inference_graph.pb \
      --output_node_names=MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

The `graph.pbtxt` is created along with the training process. I got the output node name by issuing the summarize_graph code on a pre-trained `MobileNet` model. Now, to test my model in c++ I used [label_image](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#run-label-image-in-c) (actually I have a code of my own but to make sure about the code itself I use this), with the following command:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image \
    --image=/path/to/image.jpg --input_layer=fifo_queue_Dequeue \
    --output_layer=MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1 \
    --graph=frozen_inference_graph.pb --input_width=192 \
    --input_height=42 --labels=Labels.txt --input_mean=0 \
    --input_std=255
```

To get the `input_layer`, I first used `summarize_graph`:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph \
  --in_graph=frozen_inference_graph.pb
```

But, it didn't give any input:

```
--input_layer= --input_layer_type= --input_layer_shape= --output_layer=MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

Then, I tried to use `tensorboard` by first importing the frozen model. This is the input I see there:

[image]

With the above command for `label_image` code, the model outputs only one class, no matter what the input picture is. I have the same situation with my own code, where I have tried to replicate the preprocessing steps performed by `eval_image_classifier.py` as best as I could. However, as the results are so drastically different I don't think it's a matter of preprocessing.

I checked some questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372635/running-tensorflow-classifier-model-in-c-obj-c-results-in-different-result-t). Here the person asking the question has performed quantization on the weights and he says that without this the results are the same, which isn't my case. There is also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497982/tensorflow-model-works-in-python-but-not-in-c), where the problem seems to be with specifying the wrong input layer. I guess that my own problem is perhaps because of the input layer too but I don't know how else can I determine an input layer name? I also tried `prefetch_queue/fifo_queue` but it gives me this error:

```
Running model failed: Invalid argument: Expects arg[0] to be resource but float is provided
```

I should say that I'm relatively new to Tensorflow and so far have nearly only worked with high-level APIs and not the detailed source codes. So, I would appreciate any help that isn't too professional and has enough details for a newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. Turns out, you shouldn't use the graph.pbtxt to freeze the model. In order to do the freezing the right way, we first need to export an inference graph:

```
python3 export_inference_graph.py --alsologtostderr \
   --model_name=mobilenet_v1 --output_file=unfrozen_graph.pb \
   --dataset_name=custom --dataset_dir=/path/to/data_dir
```

I have tried this one before, but using the created unfrozen_graph with freeze_graph.py gave me errors, so I let it go and then completely forgot about it. The reason for those errors was the wrong input sizes used as default ones in the [export_inference_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/export_inference_graph.py) code and the fact that I have trained my model using custom sizes.

Long story short, I froze the graph using this command:

```
python3 freeze_graph.py --input_graph=/path/to/unfrozen_graph.pb \
  --input_binary=true --input_checkpoint=/path/to/model.ckpt-CHECKPOINTNUMBER \
  --output_graph=frozen_inference_graph.pb \
  --output_node_names=MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

And this time, the frozen graph worked without a problem, the input layer name being "input" (Operation: Placeholder).